# Adobe AIR packaging for Android

Tags: java, xml, air

I seem to be getting this error... I believe I am typing everything correctly:

```
desktop/adobeairsdk/bin/adt -package -target apk -storetype pkcs12 -keystore ./desktop/mycert.p12 myApp.apk ./desktop/Untitled-1-app.xml -C ./desktop/Untitled-1.swf
```

To which I get:

```
unexpected failure: inputs not set
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: inputs not set
        at com.adobe.air.ApplicationPackager.createPackage(ApplicationPackager.java:59)
        at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseArgsAndGo(ADT.java:504)
        at com.adobe.air.ADT.run(ADT.java:361)
        at com.adobe.air.ADT.main(ADT.java:411)
```

Here is the content of my .xml file:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.5">
    <id>com.adobe.example.Untitled-1</id>
    <versionNumber>1.000</versionNumber>
    <filename>Untitled-1</filename>
    <description></description>
    <name>Untitled-1</name>
    <copyright></copyright>
    <initialWindow>
        <content>Untitled-1.swf</content>
        <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
        <transparent>false</transparent>
        <visible>true</visible>
    </initialWindow>
    <supportedProfiles>mobileDevice</supportedProfiles>
      <android>
        <manifestAdditions>
            <![CDATA[
                <manifest android:installLocation='auto'>
                    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
                    <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true"/>
                    <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/>
                    <application android:enabled="true">
                        <activity android:excludeFromRecents="false">
                            <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                            </intent-filter>
                        </activity>
                    </application>
                </manifest>
            ]]>
        </manifestAdditions>
    </android>

    <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
    <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
    <icon>
    <image16x16>AppIconsForAIRPublish/AirApp_16.png</image16x16><image32x32>AppIconsForAIRPublish/AirApp_32.png</image32x32><image48x48>AppIconsForAIRPublish/AirApp_48.png</image48x48><image128x128>AppIconsForAIRPublish/AirApp_128.png</image128x128></icon>
</application>
```

I am a bit stuck... any ideas? O_o

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Actually, I was also had same error while building the app. But when I tried the same code on windows xp it is working now. I also haven't figured out what is causing the problem in windows 7. But it is working in XP. You should try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [post](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=3437). Probably you didn't build the project before packaging it. You'll only want to create the AIR package to redistribute your application.

Comment: Thanks. It is working correctly on my system also. I must be making some mistakes in certificate generation.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem. Then I reboot win7. It works well after that.