# ADT Captive Runtime Package Command Line Error

Tags: actionscript-3, command-line, air, adt

I'm attempting (unsuccessfully) to package a captive runtime of AIR 3.3 application for Windows 7 using the command prompt.

The arguments passed to ADT are correct, as i do not receive errors and i'm prompted for the certificate password:

```
C:\Users\Geoffrey Mattie>"C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexsdk\bin\
adt.bat" -package -keystore "G:\Desktop\AIRCert.p12" -storetype pkcs12 -target b
undle "G:\Desktop\Off Air" "G:\Developer\OffAir\application.xml" -C "G:\Deve
loper\OffAir\bin\OffAir.swf" -C "G:\Developer\OffAir\assets\offAirIcon.png"
password:
```

However, after entering the password i receive this:

```
unexpected failure: inputs not set
java.lang.IllegalStateException: inputs not set
        at com.adobe.air.ApplicationPackager.createPackage(ApplicationPackager.j
ava:61)
        at com.adobe.air.nai.NativePackager.createPackage(NativePackager.java:96
)
        at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseArgsAndGo(ADT.java:564)
        at com.adobe.air.ADT.run(ADT.java:418)
        at com.adobe.air.ADT.main(ADT.java:468)

C:\Users\Geoffrey Mattie>
```

Could this be happening because my application files are located on the `G` drive while ADT and Java are on the `C` drive?  Any ideas?

Comment: Moving application files to the `C` drive did not help.

Comment: Perhaps move `-storetype` parameter up front?

Comment: Try building the project before packaging it as suggested in [this possible duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029675/adobe-air-packaging-for-android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there was a problem with my manual merging of the AIR 3.4 and Flex 4.6 SDKs.  Using the [pre-merged version](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/gaming/flex_sdk_4.6.0.23201.zip) on [Adobe's Gaming website](http://gaming.adobe.com/getstarted/) solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the name of your .exe file. Instead of:

```
-target bundle "G:\Desktop\Off Air"
```

It should probably be:

```
-target bundle "G:\Desktop\Off Air\MyApp.exe"
```

Or:

```
_target bundle "G:\Desktop\Off Air\MyApp.app"
```

Comment: this is not a solution.  i have previously tried many configurations like this including using only folder/application names without whitespace.  the same error is returned.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html